# SKNode removeFromParent sometimes removes extra children

Tags: sprite-kit, ios8, sknode

I have found that one of my SKNodes in my game removes extra children when one of its children calls removeFromParent.  To verify this, I overrode removeFromParent and added the following assertion that verifies that only one child was removed.  The assertion fails:

```
- (void) removeFromParent {
SKNode *parent = self.parent;
NSUInteger startingCount = [self.parent.children count];
[super removeFromParent];
if (parent) {
    NSAssert([[parent children] count] == startingCount - 1, @"Wrong number of children after removing one child!");
}
```

}

I've filed a bug report for this, but I'm now stuck on it because I don't have a workaround. I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this and might have a workaround for it.

Comment: what class are the affected nodes running removeFromParent? Have you found out what the extra nodes were that have been removed?

Comment: They are my own subclass of SKSpriteNode

Comment: check any code that removes itself or other nodes, you are most likely causing this issue yourself somehow because removing nodes is such a fundamental feature if it were somehow broken there would be a lot of reports about this

Comment: I agree - it would seem that this would have been reported sooner.  Which is why I've spent two days trying to figure out what's going on.  But it's clearly a bug.  My answer below seems as though it may be an undocumented nonstandard isEqual: implementation in SKNode or SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a workaround after following a hunch.

My child nodes were returning YES for isEqual:, even though they were different objects and I had not overridden isEqual: in my SKSpriteNode subclass.  It seems that the implementation of removeFromParent uses isEqual:, and when non-equal nodes returned YES, it was removing more than one.

My workaround was to override isEqual: with the following:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object {
    return self == object;
}
```